# Is it possible to use curve modifier without stretching these holes?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the second picture the holes are stretched. Is there a workaround to this?

[image]

Comment: If you want to do the holes before the bending you will get some amount of deformation. It's inevitable. Another way of doing this would be to model a segment, curved and with holes and then use an array modifier.

Comment: Hi, is that a quarter of torus? I mean proportionally ?

Comment: I've attached the blend file.Could you take a look?

Comment: Should have done it a totally different way, modelling the torus first (a standard torus).... but will look closer at your file

Comment: Also, you can use another simple deform instead of the curve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace the curve modifier by a simple deform modifier.

The point of interest is to augment the second array count until the holes stretching disappear.

Thanks to the deform modifier this is much more easy to tune than the curve modifier.

So:

- Add an empty at the same X,Y location than your grid.
- Add a simple deform / bend with an angle of 360 and turning around Z. Set the previous empty as origin.
- Rotate this empty 180 around X.

Now tuning:

- Augment the second array count to 180 (or around that).
- The simple deform will make a larger ring.
- But you can now scale it in X, Y (not Z) to readjust the shape to the speaker diameter.

You can see above:

- The result
- The added empty
- The scale given to the grid
- And the added simple deform parameters

[image]

[image]